# How to toggle console.log in a jQuery widget?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, logging, jquery-plugins

I've been working on some jQuery widget for work/fun lately ([github](http://github.com/mgcrea)) and there is still something that is bothering me.

When i use a widget in my app, i want to be able to pass a debug option, that will enable or disable logging (using console.log) entirely only in this plugin.

---

**best solution so far :**

from :

```
(function( $, undefined ) {

})(jQuery);
```

to :

```
(function( $, console, undefined ) {

    if (!o.debug) console = { log: function(){} };

})(jQuery, console);
```

**There is one problem left**

If i load two widgets like :

```
$myDiv.myWidget({debug: true});
$myDiv2.myWidget({debug: false});
```

I won't have later debug from 1st instantiation. Any ideas ?

---

[original]
So far i've used a piece of code i've found on the internet :

```
var logger = function() {
    var oldConsoleLog = null;
    var pub = {};

    pub.enableLogger = function enableLogger() {
        if(oldConsoleLog == null) return;
        window['console']['log'] = oldConsoleLog;
    };

    pub.disableLogger = function disableLogger() {
        oldConsoleLog = console.log;
        window['console']['log'] = function() {};
    };

    return pub;
}();
```

Then on `_create()` i can do sth like :

```
if (!o.debug) {
        logger.disableLogger();
}
```

Looked quite good however, it is not plugin specific, as it will disable console.log for my entire app.

One important point is that i want to be able to keep console.log line logging feature (no wrapping of console.log since as far as i know / tried, it will replace logging line info with useless wrapped call line).

Thank you !

Comment: Isn't window['console']['log'] the same as window.console.log?

Comment: yep, same thing, should have used dot (not my piece of code) since it's cleaner.

Comment: Why not `if (!o.debug) this.console = { log: function(){} };`? The downsides are:

* It's adding an extra property to `this`
* It's inconvenient to call this.console.log everytime

But it server your purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest option I can think of is to override console inside your scope. Like this.

```
(function(console){
  if (!o.debug) console = { log: function(){} };

  // Rest of your code goes here
})(console);
```

Comment: There is still a problem with this method. Distinct instantiation of same plugin will conflict.

Comment: It's working for me. Here's a more complete example of what I meant: https://gist.github.com/789302

Answer (score 1):

I find that architecture odd. It seems to me that there are two ways to solve this. 1) Create a debug plugin, or 2) have your plugin call console.log

In the first case - I would always instantiate the debug plugin, either with `true` or `false` as the debug option. And I would always have my other plugin call the logging function (if that logging function exists)

In both cases I would not litter the code with if statements. I would have my other plugin have its own log call. In the first case it would check if the debug plugin exists. In the second case it would check it's own `debug` option to see if it should console.log or not.

Comment: this does not seem to be a good solution since i loose line tracking from console.log in either ways (will always retrieve line of plugin call).

Comment: if you print out the appropriate context and variables you should be fine. console.log doesn't output lines anyhow (iirc).

Comment: Chrome console does print lines, so useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've never really used brackets to access attributes of the `window`, but that looks like it might do the job.  Though note if you call `disableLogger()` twice without calling `enableLogger()` in between, you will not be able to re-enable logging.